# Flash AS3 - How to replace/swap an image inside a movieclip?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a bitmap rpeviously loaded and added as child to a movielip mc
then i want to load another image later and remove thatchild and replace with the new one..
for some reason my code doesnt work..i dont know what im doing wrong

i add a listener to a thumbnail called `openBigImage`
so basically the new file path and filename should replace the previous image

`imgLoader` is a movieclip that contains varius image previously delared as `img0, img1` etc..

`theThumbs` contain the images filenames as string

my question is: should img.addChildAt(bitmapContent,0); works as a swapper function? i can remove the img child but i cant replace it...

```
function openBigImage(e) 
{
    var e = e.target;
    var i = e.parent.name1;
    var z = e.parent.name2;
    var tu = theThumbs[i][z];   
    var img =  imgLoader.getChildByName("img" + i);
    var newimg:Loader = new Loader();
    var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(tu);    
    newimg.load(fileRequest);
    newimg.name = i;
    newimg.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadCompleted2);
    img.removeChildAt(0);
}
function onLoadCompleted2(e:Event):void {
    var bitmapContent:Bitmap = Bitmap( e.target.content );
    bitmapContent.smoothing = true;
    var i = e.target.loader.name;
    var img =  imgLoader.getChildByName("img" + i); 
    trace("img" + i)
    img.addChildAt(bitmapContent,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question and no solution ?

```
function onLoadCompleted2(e: Event):void
{
    // ...
    trace("replacing image");
    var index: int = img.getChildIndex(oldImage);
    img.removeChildAt(index);
    img.addChildAt(newImage, index);
}
```

As alternative you can use a `Sprite` and then just clear and fill it with the new image.